# Weblogic Inserting Teradata PERIOD datatype

Tags: java, weblogic, teradata

I've been having issues inserting / updating a period column.

According to a sample from the Teradata website located [here](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T22007JD.java.txt), you should be able to create your own java.sql.Struct implmentation which you then provide as a parameter.  I've done this, and once I actually hit the database, Weblogic throws an error stating my implementation of the Struct failed to be loaded (`ClassNotFoundException`)

Do I have to I have to inject this into the Weblogic class loader somehow?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. What's the actual stack trace? Where should that class be? In your .war/.ear file?

Comment: The stack trace is sort of irrelevant, it's a class loader issue with weblogic. I took weblogic out of the mix, and just tried the same SQL against the datasource with my Struct implementation, and it worked fine.

Comment: How is it deployed to weblogic? It's obvious you have some sort of packaging issue with your deployment but without that information it's anyones guess

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to Weblogic managing the JDBC connection, and the application loading the data source through JNDI, Weblogic is doing the actual execution of the SQL.  When the SQL is executed, it looks for this Struct implementation, doesn't find it on the Classpath, and throws an exception.

One solution is to wrap this class in it's own jar, and deploy it to $DOMAIN_ROOT/lib.  After a server reboot, the implementation will be bootstrapped through the class loader, and available for use.